# How can I check if a JS file has been included already?

Tags: javascript

I have split my javascript in different files. I want to prevent, that javascript files are loaded twice. How can I do that?

Comment: Just include them only once. No seriously how do you include them?

Comment: are you able to modify the content of the JS files

Comment: Usually you should only have one or maybe a few more js files (concatenation/minification) so it is pretty simple to check that by hand.

Comment: Are you using any server-side language, like PHP for example? If so then you can create a function, called `addJs()` (for example) that only outputs the `<script>` tag if that script hasn't already been added.

Comment: Perhaps relevant:  http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 29):

Here's a test to see if a script has been included based on the path to the js file:

```
function isScriptAlreadyIncluded(src){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) 
       if(scripts[i].getAttribute('src') == src) return true;
    return false;
}
```

It will work for all scripts not loaded through AJAX, though you may want to modify it if you have jsonp code running.

Comment: I like this answer because it shows it's possible to keep track of which files have been included, but in practice I would never recommend this approach, since although you may have your scripts split up into different files now, you may want to combine them later into one file for better performance, in which case this approach would no longer work.

Comment: @MattBrowne I agree in principle, but often it is not that simple. Sometimes one is working within a framework (or for some other reason is not in control) which may or may not include a script file.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the js file was loaded by other means (via js for example).

That's when `window.performance` can come in handy. Instead of checking among the `script` tags, as suggested in other answers, we can check among the resources **loaded**, with:

```
let resources = performance.getEntries()
    .filter(e => e.entryType === 'resource')
    .map(e => e.name);
if (resources.indexOf("//domain.com/path/to/script.js") === -1) {
    // Script was not yet loaded.
}
```

The `window.performance` browser compatibility is not bad nowadays:
https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_performance_getentries

If we want to check both the `script` tags (for all script tags in the DOM up to that point, including URLs of scripts that may not yet have been loaded) *and* the `window.resources` (for all scripts loaded up to that point, including the ones loaded via js), we could put it together in a function:

```
function is_script_already_included(src){
  const found_in_resources = performance.getEntries()
      .filter(e => e.entryType === 'resource')
      .map(e => e.name)
      .indexOf(src) !== -1;
  const found_in_script_tags = document.querySelectorAll(`script[src*="${src}"]`).length > 0;
  return found_in_resources || found_in_script_tags;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code and its compatibility?

Comment: Hello @martin-braun, I added some context, as requested.

Answer (score 3):

Don't include them twice. It's you who's doing the includes, after all.

If you're doing those inclusions dynamically, though, you may check whether some global function or object has been set by the script. For example, if I have the script below in a file:

```
Foo = function () {};
```

And then I include it like this:

```
<script src="../foo.js"></script>
```

Before that script tag is parsed by the browser, `Foo` is `undefined`. After the tag is processed, `Foo` is a `Function`. You could use some logic based on that to determine whether you should include some file or not.

Answer (score 2):

I have tackled this using a generic self-invoking function added at the bottom of each dynamically loaded script.

First -  by declaring a new empty array in my base file or a script that will always be loaded, ie the main page in my case index.php

```
var scriptsLoaded = new Array();
```

Then add a self executing function to the end of the loaded script:

```
(function () { scriptsLoaded.push( 'this_script_name.js' ) })();
```

With this approach any filename in the scriptsLoaded array should only refer to scripts that have been fully loaded already. Simply checking this array would indicate whether a script has been loaded which can also be used as a check for whether to execute on-load style functions for whatever the script is needed for

Answer (score 1):

Not using any framework (that I know of), you can only do so by checking if a certain variable  in the global scope has already been declared.

You could declare a variable `var include1 = true;` inside `include1.js`, and do something like

```
if (window.include1 !== true) {
    // load file dynamically
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to manually track this and make sure. UweB's suggestion would also work.

You could also check out Require.js which could help you to organize your files.