# Symfony2 : best practice to embed JS in twig form widget

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony, widget

I'm currently designing a bundle for adding SEO fields in any form. I got some JS, mainly for AJAX calls.
I saw some bundles including JS inline in the widget.

Is it the best way to do? Can this be externalized?

Thanks for your answers,

Nicolas

Comment: I suppose you could keep your JS code in an external JS file, which you call in the widget. Then all your JS code will be "externalized".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As far as you know and as a complement, is there any built-in system to avoid JS inclusion repeition in case several widgets are included?

Comment: You would need to make it a part of your JS code in your widget. Quick search brought me here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18155347 . See answer from @cwallenpoole.